# Response of a submit form is adding < pre > to json

Tags: extjs

I'm working with ext 4.0.7.   I'm trying to upload a text file and process it.  Here is my js code

```
}, {
    xtype: 'form',
    id: 'uploadAccountForm',
    name: 'uploadAccountForm',
    border: false,
    padding: '5px, 45px',
    //      standardSubmit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    fileUpload: true,
    items: [{
            xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
            minWidth: 96,
            name: 'file',
            id: 'multipacAccountList',
            fieldLabel: bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.label.accountlist'),
            buttonText: bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.button.upload'),
            buttonOnly: false,
            vtype:'fileUpload'
        }]
},{    
    xtype: 'button',
    text: bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.button.getresults'),
    minWidth: 96,
    margin: 10,
    name: 'multipacGet',
    id: 'multipacGet',
    handler: function() {
        var account = Ext.getCmp('multipacAccount').getValue();
        var company = Ext.getCmp('multipacCompany').getValue();
        var accountList = Ext.getCmp('multipacAccountList').getValue();
        var companyList = Ext.getCmp('multipacCompanyList').getValue();
        var dlg = this.up('multiPacAdminDlg');
        if (account !== "" && company !== "") {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('iCRM', Ext.String.format(bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.button.getresults.both')));
        } else if (account !== "") {
            iCRM.app.fireEvent("showMultiPacDefModal");
        //    getResults("account", account, dlg.down('#grid'));
        } else if (company !== "") {
            iCRM.app.fireEvent("showMultiPacDefModal");
        //    getResults("company", company, dlg.down('#grid'));
        } else if (accountList !== "" && companyList !== "") {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('iCRM', Ext.String.format(bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.button.getresults.both')));
            var accountList = Ext.getCmp('multipacAccountList');
            accountList.superclass.setValue.call(accountList, "");
            var companyList = Ext.getCmp('multipacCompanyList');
            companyList.superclass.setValue.call(companyList, "");
        } else if (accountList !== "") {
            this.fileUpload("account");
        } else if (companyList !== "") {
            this.fileUpload("company");
        } else {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('iCRM', Ext.String.format(bundle.getMsg('error.search.regular.missing_criteria')));
        }
    },
    fileUpload: function(category) {
        var form = "";
        var url = "";
        if (category === "company") {
            url = "../search/uploadCompanies";
            form = Ext.getCmp('uploadCompanyForm').getForm();
        } else if (category === "account") {
            url = "../search/uploadAccounts";
            form = Ext.getCmp("uploadAccountForm").getForm();
        }
        debugger;
        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                url: url,
                method:'POST',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                success:function (form, action) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded.');
                },
                failure: function (form, action) {
                    if (action.result.code==='Invalid Record') {
                        Ext.Msg.alert("Error", Ext.String.format(bundle.getMsg('label.modal.additional_tools.multipacadmin.upload.records.message')));
                    } else  {
                        Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Your file has NOT been uploaded. " + action.result.code);
                    }
                },
                callback:function (form, action) {
                    debugger;
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded. Callback');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, {
```

And this is my java code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAccounts",  method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Map<String, ? extends Object> uploadAccounts(FileUploadBean uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws IOException {

        CommonsMultipartFile accountFile = uploadItem.getFile();
        String[] records = processFile(accountFile);

        Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (records != null) {
            if (records.length>100){
                jsonMap.put("success", Boolean.TRUE);
                jsonMap.put("code", "Too many Record");
                jsonMap.put("data", records);
            } else {
                jsonMap.put("success", Boolean.TRUE);
                jsonMap.put("data", records);
            }
        } else {
            jsonMap.put("success", Boolean.FALSE);
            jsonMap.put("code", "Invalid Record");
        }
        return jsonMap; 
    }
```

The file is uploaded, and I can process it without problems.  But, when I send the response to my js, I'm getting this:

Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: < pre >{"data":["876567","676567","678988","654345","654321","665654","676556","678780","909877","454343","434343"],"success":true}

I analized my response with firebug, and I can see that the response is just:
{"data":["876567","676567","678988","654345","654321","665654","676556","678780","909877","454343","434343"],"success":true}

So, somewhere, somehow, I'm getting added the < pre > tags.   The only solutiion that i found was to modify the ext core, adding this lines, to the decode function, to remove the < pre > or < embed > tags.

```
Ext.each([/<\/?pre[^>]*>/g, /<\/?embed[^>]*>/g], function (s) {            
    json = json.replace(s, "");
});
```

But this is not the solution that we are looking for.

I tried a standardSubmit, but that is redirecting me a new page, or tab, or iframe, and i'm not reaching the success/failure functions from my submit
I also tryied to set the response to application/json contentType, or html/txt...  but I'm getting same response.
And, as far as I know, I can't perform an ajax request, because I'm uploading files.
So, any idea, or suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution:
   For Ext 4.0, you need to set the contentType of the response like "html/text", and then, sorround the json string with  tags.

Take a look on this for further information.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269683-Response-of-a-submit-form-is-adding-lt-pre-gt-to-json&p=987969#post987969